# Conflict between \mathabx and \amssymb

Tags: symbols, incompatibility, amssymb, mathabx

I need to use `\ldbrack` and `\rdbrack` symbols from the package `\mathabx`, but when I use the `\mathabx` with the `\amssymb` package (previously installed) it is causing me an issue with symbols: `\subseteq`, `\cap`, `\cup`, etc

```
\documentclass{book}   
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

This a example, 

$$A\subseteq B=\emptyset A\cap B\cup C$$

$$x + y \ldbrack z \rdbrack$$
\end{document}
```

The following picture was created using `\mathabx` and `\amssymb`.

[image: Imagen1]

And  the following picture was created using only `\amssymb`.

[image: Imagen2]

Please notice that on imagen 1, `\cap`, `\cup`, etc; are different and I require the other ones.

Is there a way to use both packages without mess up my document symbols?
Thanks.

Comment: Most likely you can solve your problem using [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `mathabx` provides also the symbols in `amssymb`, but uses its own version. See [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386) for adding just a few ones from `mathabx`.

Comment: if it's only the double brackets you need, those are also available as `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` in the st. mary road font; `\usepackage{stmaryrd}`.  (`texdoc stmaryrd` for the documentation.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `mathabx` package is not compatible with `amssymb`; besides, it changes *all* math symbols.

You can use, instead, `stmaryrd`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A\subseteq B=\emptyset \\
A\cap B\cup C \\
x + y \llbracket z \rrbracket
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to import the symbols from `mathabx`, according to the guidelines in [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764) you can do as follows.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5>    matha5
  <5.5-6.5> matha6 
  <6.5-7.5> matha7
  <7.5-8.5> matha8
  <8.5-9.5> matha9
  <9.5-11>  matha10
  <11->     matha12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<-> mathx10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\ldbrack}{4}{matha}{"76}{mathx}{"30}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rdbrack}{5}{matha}{"77}{mathx}{"38}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A\subseteq B=\emptyset \\
A\cap B\cup C \\
x + y \ldbrack z \rdbrack
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would the cheap `\let\oldcup\cup \usepackage{mathabx} \let\cup\oldcup` work?

Comment: @Manuel They're not the only symbols that get changed. And that method won't work.