# \(\bigominus\) and \(\bigoslash\)?

Tags: symbols

There are these

```
\odot, \ominus, \oplus, \oslash, \otimes
```

as well as the large versions

```
\bigodot,  \bigoplus \& \bigotimes.
```

How may one get

```
\bigominus \& \bigoslash?
```

Edit:

Following a suggestion and use the mathabx or Mnsymbol package, which both have the symbols, is not a viable option, it seems. For mathabx conflicts with amssymb, and the latter is needed. Besides, my understanding is that MnSymbol has been much criticized, and I recall that I had problems myself.

Perhaps importing the two symbols can be done, or perhaps they can be built from scratch?

Comment: Both the `mathabx` and `MnSymbol` packages provide `\bigominus` and `\bigoslash`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. My understanding is that those do not combine well with other packages needed for mathematical texts. Isn't that right?

Comment: It depends on which basic math fonts you employ (something you've not provided any information about).

Comment: @Mico How do these combine: amsmath, asthma, mathtools, marvosym, stmaryrd, yfonts, tikz?

Comment: Sorry, but that's an entirely new question. You know the drill.

Comment: @Mico I don't even know whether I listed basic math fonts.

Comment: @Mico The answer here 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323548/conflict-between-mathabx-and-amssymb

points out that mathabx is not compatible with amssymb, and I need the latter. 
 
I have seen several advice to stay away from MnSymbol, and I experienced difficulties myself.

So it seems that I should not use either of those packages.

Perhaps there may be a way to import just the two symbols I asked for, but I am not able to do that. 

If not, there may be ways to construct the symbols from scratch, which I am also unable to do on my own.

Comment: First half is duplicate of [math mode - \oplus and \bigoplus with vertical or horizontal line instead of cross - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623872/oplus-and-bigoplus-with-vertical-or-horizontal-line-instead-of-cross/623896#623896).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `scalerel` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\let\bigopsize\bigoplus
\def\bigoplus{{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\oplus}{\bigopsize}}}
\def\bigominus{{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\ominus}{\bigopsize}}}
\def\bigodot{{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\odot}{\bigopsize}}}
\def\bigotimes{{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\otimes}{\bigopsize}}}
\def\bigoslash{{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\oslash}{\bigopsize}}}



\begin{document}

$\bigoplus \bigominus \bigodot \bigotimes \bigoslash$

$a^\bigoplus$

\end{document}
```

[image]